# Woocommerce get variations API does not always return newly created variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

On woocommerce, I add a new variation to a product. I have a hook configured for `product.updated` to my API.

Once the hook is received on my API for the updated product, I do a `get variations` API call hoping to get a list including the newly added variation.

Sometimes, the response includes the newly added variations. Other times, it does not.

The same thing happens with updating variations. If I update the `regular_price` and publish the changes, `product.updated` hook fires to my API. When I do `get variations` again, that variation in the response still has the former price.

I realized that if I call `get variations` like 1 or 2 mins after `product.updated` hook was fired, I will receive all variations including updates in the response.

---

What could be going on in woocommerce?
Does woocommerce generate an id for a variation and trigers a hook before taking time to build the object? This might explain why it works after a while.
Any other ideas?

- I'm using `Automattic\WooCommerce\Client` lib.
- woocommerce REST v3
- woocommere v3.9.2

Comment: Can you share more insights on how you are trying to achieve triggering behavior? It seems it has nothing to do with API library or REST API itself but more related to correcting hooks & filters at right point.